# maven.compiler.target in pom.xml not working

Tags: java, maven

there are some properties in my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>${java.version}</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
</properties>
```

but when I check the effective-pom, I found they became:

```
    <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>11.0.2</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>11.0.2</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11.0.2</maven.compiler.target>
```

(my JDK version is 11.0.2.)

but my question is, why they became to '11.0.2' while I've already let them be 11 manually?

(and it will cause error when mvn compile: "Error: Java: invalid target release: 11.0.2"(translation from the CN message, I'am not sure whether it's the same with the really En message))

the new info found after post this question 30 min: these property values are overrided by a actived profiler in settings.xml with the same name:

```
<profile>
    <id>java11</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>11</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>${java.version}</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

but the question is the same: since the value of <java.version> in the settings.xml is also '11', why when inlining to the maven.compiler.... properties, it became to '11.0.2'?(there is no '11.0.2' appearence in any places)

Comment: Most likely "java.version" is a reserved property set by Maven. Call your own property something else.

Comment: Why is there a profile in a `settings.xml` does not belong there nor makes it sense... also using `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>` instead of target/source etc. starting from JDK9+...